# couchdb, pouchdb filters and views

Tags: filter, couchdb, view, pouchdb

I'm building an app base on couchdb and pouchdb.

let's say this example:

```
doc profile { _id:"1", name:"john", likes: ["2222","1111"] }

doc likes { _id:"2222", value:"true" }, { _id:"1111", value:"false" }
```

I want to get only those docs on the user local database using pouchdb sync or replication.

I have created filters on couchdb but I can only filter profile doc because i have the user_id after login but likes wont replicate because I can't filter it.

I tried multiple replications to use different filters on use side but it didn't work. I was thinking if I can access likes doc in couchdb filter to check if likes ids included in profile.likes array?

Or is there is other solutions like views?

Comment: Is their any particular reason why your likes are not nested into the profile document?

Comment: I was trying to reach you, when i found your comment on another question.
Image there is 1000 like each one or two months .. i don't see it as a good solution. 
specially using couchdb .. because there is filter as powerful tool. can you recommend any book about filters and views

Comment: Let's say you want to sync only information related to the current user, you can either add the user information to each of your documents or you can group your documents with the per-user database pattern.

Comment: I figured it out. I have another a question since you are here. i want to ask you directly. i'm passing query_params but i need to pass an array ? is that possible. example: i pass the array of likes => let optionsWithFilter = {
        live: true,
        retry: true,
        continuous: true,
        filter: "myFilter/filter",
        query_params:{
            "likes":likes
        }
    };

Comment: Yeah you can passy any JSON object.

Comment: I have pass a json object and test it. it worked fine. but when i tried but i have an array on couchdb document .. i want to test if this array contains an id that i have passed on query_params ?

Comment: Perhaps, you should create a separate question and add more details on this issue